# Vertically centre align text next to icon

Tags: html, css

I have 2 blocks of text with a circle next to each of them.

I'd like to vertically centre align the blocks of text with the icon. Right now if one of the blocks of text is just one line long, it is forced to the top rather than centre.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cq0cj74o/

```css
.circle {
    background: #1d1d1b;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

div {
  display:block;
  height:100px
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="circle"><span>1</span></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum </p>
</div>

<div>
<p class="circle"><span>2</span></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` for this. You just have to add `align-items: center` on flex-container and also remove margin auto from `.circle`.

If you want to center text inside circle you can also use `Flexbox` for that [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cq0cj74o/1/).

```css
.circle {
  background: #1d1d1b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  width: 50px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="circle"><span>1</span></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="circle"><span>2</span></p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum orem ipsum orem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Many many thanks, Nenad for your detailed response. It has helped me greatly :-)